# How to replace a specific char in a substring of a long text?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

From javascript, given this multi-lines text (stocked in a variable):

```
+++ diagramme
graph TD
    A[fooA] ==> B[fooB]
    style A color:blue
    B --> C[(<img src="https://c7.alamy.com/compfr/jcdcx7/image-d-icone-de-soleil-jcdcx7.jpg" width="50">)]
    C --> D[fooD]
    B --> D
    click D "https://fii.com" _blank
+++
```

I'm looking for a way to replace all " by the char ' within the img tag. In the img tag, the number of attributes can vary.

In my example, the result expected is :

```
+++ diagramme
graph TD
    A[fooA] ==> B[fooB]
    style A color:blue
    B --> C[(<img src='https://c7.alamy.com/compfr/jcdcx7/image-d-icone-de-soleil-jcdcx7.jpg' width='50'>)]
    C --> D[fooD]
    B --> D
    click D "https://fii.com" _blank
+++
```

I know how use regex (thanks amazing website like https://regex101.com/ ! ), so I can capture the img tag with this simple pattern /(<img)(.*)(>)/g . But I don't know how I can replace all occurences of a specific char (here ") by a another (here ') in a substring obtained via a regex.

edit : the position and the number of the img tags can vary in the structure '+++ diagramme ... +++'. Below an another example :

```
+++ diagramme
graph TD
    A[fooA] ==> B[(<img src="https://fuu/image1.jpg" width="50">)]
    B --> C[fooC]
    click B "https://faa.com" _blank
    C --> D[(<img src="https://fuu/image2.jpg">)]
+++
```

and the expected result :

```
+++ diagramme
graph TD
    A[fooA] ==> B[(<img src='https://fuu/image1.jpg' width='50'>)]
    B --> C[fooC]
    click B "https://faa.com" _blank
    C --> D[(<img src='https://fuu/image2.jpg'>)]
+++
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback function:

```js
const test = `+++ diagramme
graph TD
    A[fooA] ==> B[fooB]
    style A color:blue
    B --> C[(<img src="https://c7.alamy.com/compfr/jcdcx7/image-d-icone-de-soleil-jcdcx7.jpg" width="50">)]
    C --> D[fooD]
    B --> D
    click D "https://fii.com" _blank
+++`
console.log(test.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, (x) => x.replace(/"/g, "'") ))
```

Comment: Much better solution than mine, I forgot you can do that

Comment: ouuu interesting ! I try this now !

Comment: yeah , its work ! its alliiveeeee !thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

1. Getting all the image tags using RegExp
2. Replacing the `"` with `'` in for all the matched results
3. Replace the image tags with the fixed image tags or you can create 2 substrings, before the match and after the match + match length and concat it with the fixed image (don’t forget to fix the indexes of the next image match if the new image tag is in different length than the first image tag)